# kubernetes creation of pod using service account

Tags: kubernetes

I am assuming, because pod contains service account ( by default mounting default service account), pod is being created.

If i do autoMountServiceAccountToken as false, then also my pod is creating. In that case how authentication happening ?

kubectl command ( client ) + service account token --> requesting to create pod -> server is validating and accepting request to create the pod.

is my understand wrong ?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Typically, the serviceaccount is not used to create pods: *your* account is used to create pods (and your code can then use the serviceaccount token to authenticate if it needs to interact with the kubernetes api).

Comment: yes in that case, if default service account is there then authentication/authorization happening with default service account, when I specify autoMountServiceAccountToken: false, then service account is not mounted, if that is the case, how it is getting service account ? how as a kubectl command is successful ?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question where you're running `kubectl`. If you could update your question to include a complete series of steps to reproduce the behavior you're asking about it would be easier to answer.

Comment: I have installed minikube in my local ubuntu environment. so in the terminal i am running kubectl command. I have edit my pod yaml and provide flag autoMountServiceAccountToken value as false  This is my pod :                  apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: alpine
spec:
   containers:
           -  image: nginx
              name: my-nginx
              ports:
                      -   containerPort: 8080
   automountServiceAccountToken: false
   nodeSelector:
      prize: emerald

Comment: If kubectl is the client ,  minikube is the cluster, when I provide serviceAccountToken as false, then how kubectl as client authenticatingwith minikube cluster ?  If i dont provide any flag then default serviceaccount is considered that has token (secret) and ca.crt , but if i specify automountServiceAccountToken as false then which service account it will take to authenticate with cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

To check which actions can be performed in an cluster, below command can be executed. If it return yes then pods can be created.

```
kubectl auth can-i create <resource-name>
kubectl auth can-i create pod
```

To understand more details or restrict to creation of resources in cluster please refer [Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/), [Authorisation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) documentation and also [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/)